# I want to make simple if else statement with input form using laravel but without database

Tags: php, laravel, forms, if-statement

I want to make a simple if else statement with form in laravel without using a database. I want to make the form can make me choose as John, Jack, or James. Can anyone please help me show how to code the form

```
//I want to make a form in here
@if($name == 'John')
<h2 class="pt-2 tm-color-primary tm-post-tittle">Hai {{$name}}!</h2>
@elseif($name == 'Jack')
<h2 class="pt-2 tm-color-primary tm-post-tittle">Hai {{$name}}!</h2>
@elseif($name == 'James')
<h2 class="pt-2 tm-color-primary tm-post-tittle">Hai {{$name}}!</h2>
@else
<h2 class="pt-2 tm-color-primary tm-post-tittle">I dont know you</h2>
@endif
```

Comment: Sidenote, the 2 `elseif()` statements are redundant, since they run the same code as the first `if()`, rewrite to `@if($name == 'John' || $name == 'Jack' || $name == 'James') ... @else ... @endif`

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array and check if `$name` is [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
$checkNames = ['John', 'Jack', 'James'];

@if(in_array($name, $checkNames))
   <h2 class="pt-2 tm-color-primary tm-post-tittle">Hai {{$name}}!</h2>
@else
   <h2 class="pt-2 tm-color-primary tm-post-tittle">I dont know you</h2>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to create your "pseudo storage". In an array you can store all available names. Then you can check in your if condition if the name are in your "pseudo storage" / array. `isset()` returns `true or false`.

```php
$names = ['John', 'Jack', 'James'];
$name = 'Jack';

@if(isset($names[$name]))
   <h2 class="pt-2 tm-color-primary tm-post-tittle">Hai {{$name}}!</h2>
@else
   <h2 class="pt-2 tm-color-primary tm-post-tittle">I dont know you</h2>
@endif
```